# How do I serialize this JSON response from API in Python?

Tags: python, json, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

The response from the API is:

```
{"states":[{"state_id":1,"state_name":"Andaman and Nicobar Islands"},{"state_id":2,"state_name":"Andhra Pradesh"},{"state_id":3,"state_name":"Arunachal Pradesh"},{"state_id":4,"state_name":"Assam"},{"state_id":5,"state_name":"Bihar"},{"state_id":6,"state_name":"Chandigarh"},{"state_id":7,"state_name":"Chhattisgarh"},{"state_id":8,"state_name":"Dadra and Nagar Haveli"},{"state_id":37,"state_name":"Daman and Diu"},{"state_id":9,"state_name":"Delhi"},{"state_id":10,"state_name":"Goa"},{"state_id":11,"state_name":"Gujarat"},{"state_id":12,"state_name":"Haryana"},{"state_id":13,"state_name":"Himachal Pradesh"},{"state_id":14,"state_name":"Jammu and Kashmir"},{"state_id":15,"state_name":"Jharkhand"},{"state_id":16,"state_name":"Karnataka"},{"state_id":17,"state_name":"Kerala"},{"state_id":18,"state_name":"Ladakh"},{"state_id":19,"state_name":"Lakshadweep"},{"state_id":20,"state_name":"Madhya Pradesh"},{"state_id":21,"state_name":"Maharashtra"},{"state_id":22,"state_name":"Manipur"},{"state_id":23,"state_name":"Meghalaya"},{"state_id":24,"state_name":"Mizoram"},{"state_id":25,"state_name":"Nagaland"},{"state_id":26,"state_name":"Odisha"},{"state_id":27,"state_name":"Puducherry"},{"state_id":28,"state_name":"Punjab"},{"state_id":29,"state_name":"Rajasthan"},{"state_id":30,"state_name":"Sikkim"},{"state_id":31,"state_name":"Tamil Nadu"},{"state_id":32,"state_name":"Telangana"},{"state_id":33,"state_name":"Tripura"},{"state_id":34,"state_name":"Uttar Pradesh"},{"state_id":35,"state_name":"Uttarakhand"},{"state_id":36,"state_name":"West Bengal"}],"ttl":24}
```

I am trying to send this data to my Telegram bot.

```
states_url = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states"
res =  requests.get(states_url,headers={'User-Agent':my_headers})
bot.send_message(chat_id = chat_id, text=response)
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: replace `text=response` with `text=res.json()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to send the `Response` object, while you want either the Python object from the response, in which case you can use `res.json()`, or you want the raw text of the response, in which case you can use `res.text`.